# Como enviar informação de um formulário dinâmico?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Tenho que fazer um formulário em que lá vou ter esta tabela, só que em vez de ser estática vai ser dinâmica, a pessoa pode introduzir 1 familiar, 2 ,3 ,4, 10, os que ela quiser. Para isso eu estou a usar `JQUERY`, e sempre que a pessoa clica num  botão de adicionar vai acrescentando uma linha nova à tabela, esta parte sei fazer.
A minha duvida é a seguinte, como é que depois mando a informação toda para a base de dados, disseram me que ia ter que armazenar num *array*, só que eu *array´s* em PHP não sou muito bom.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EXEMPLO MEU

parte html

```html
<form method="post" id="formulario" action="dados.php">  
        
                <div id="telefone">  
            <p><label>Nome</label><input type="text" class="fone" name="agregado[]" size="15" /><span class="adicionar">Adicionar registo</span></p>  
            <p><label>telefone</label><input type="text" class="fone" name="agregado[]" size="15" /></p>  
       </div>  
            <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btEnviar" name="btEnviar" />  
     </form>
```

PARTE DADOS.PHP

```
$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            echo "Erro na liga??o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }

$result = count($_POST["agregado"]);
$agregado=$_POST["agregado"];
var_dump($agregado);

for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++){
    $sql="insert into teste (nome) values ('$agregado[i]', '$agregado[i]')";//DUVIDA
    echo $sql;
}
```

Pronto eu chego a esta parte faço mesmo o `var_dump($agregado)` em que a saida é algo tipo isto

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "pessoa" [1]=> string(3) "123" }
```

isto é a saida para o caso de introduzir 1 pessoa, se meter 2 a saida vai ser:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "pessoa" [1]=> string(3) "123" [2]=> string(5) "pessoa_2" [3]=> string(3) "234" }
```

e por ai em diante

Como é que eu faço para inserir cada posição do array no seu devido sitio?

Eu faço o for para percorrer as posições todas do array mas depois não consigo fazer com que introduza a posição correta..

Comment: O que você pode fazer é: no name de cada input você adiciona `[]`. Exemplo: `input name="name[]"`. Ou seja, você pode criar infinitos inputs com esse mesmo name (`name[]`). E toda essa informação terá no `$_POST['name']` como um array. Aqui nos comentários é difícil exemplificar, mas vou deixar para alguém fazer um exemplo melhor para você...

Comment: pois a minha duvida tambem era no name do input. Só uma coisa, se eu tiver 5 input name="name[]" no final a variavel $_POST['name'] vai conter o valor desses 5 inputs, é assim ou estou errado?

Comment: Exatamente. A saída vai ser mais ou menos assim (var_dump): `'name' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '41234' (length=5)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '41234' (length=5)
      3 => string '41234' (length=5)`. Então é só você percorrer esse array (for) e fazer o insert das informações por cada posição que você passa, exemplo: `"INSERT .... VALUES ($_POST['name']['2'], $_POST['outro'][2]....)"`.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo para você tomar como base: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/477945-insert-input-dinamico/?p=1899235

Comment: Não percebi a parte do insert, editei a minha pergunta e acrescentei lá um código de exemplo para ver se você me consegue ajudar

Comment: Assim que possível, vejo para você.

Comment: Acredito que o html certo seria `<input type="text" class="fone" name="nome[]" size="15" />` e `<input type="text" class="fone" name="telefone[]" size="15" />`, (observe o name do input) do jeito que o seu está agora pode acabar se confundindo posteriormente.... Assim o nome e telefone vem em arrays separados. E em cada interação você pode usar `$nomes[$i]` e `$telefones[$i]`. Não sei a estrutura da sua tabela, então não posso indicar um SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, se sabes fazer a parte de jQuery é um começo. A partir do jQuery podes enviar os valores para o PHP através de POST de várias formas, JSON, array, csv, ou outro.

Imaginando um csv, para facilitar o exemplo, imaginemos que temos um campo que traz texto, em que o delimitador das várias linhas é um ";" e que o delimitador dos campos é uma ","

```
// variavel POSTed por jQuery
$csv = "nome1,parentesco1,idade1,contacto1;nome2,parentesco2,idade2,contacto2"
```

Se o campo do formulário se chamar 'items', deve aceder-lhe usando $_POST['items']. Depois:

```
$items = explode(";", $csv);

foreach ($items as $item) {
$colunas = explode(",", $item);
// Inserir aqui na base de dados, usando $coluna[0], $coluna[1], ..., $coluna[N]
}
```

Atenção que este código foi feito da minha cabeça, não está testado.